# Main app unable to see Kotlin Multiplatform Library's dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, kotlin-multiplatform, multiplatform

Trying to create a sample **multiplatform library**, which **depends on a library** (e.g. implementation(kotlinx.datetime)) in the commonMain. The **library will expose a method** (e.g. getDateTime), which will **return an object (e.g. Instant)**. I did a test for it, it is working well within the library project. This library is eventually published to a local repository as an AAR file.

Below is the build config file for the library.

> plugins {
> alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
> alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary) }
>
> kotlin {
> targetHierarchy.default()
>
> ```
> androidTarget {
>     compilations.all {
>         kotlinOptions {
>             jvmTarget = "1.8"
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> listOf(
>     iosX64(),
>     iosArm64(),
>     iosSimulatorArm64()
> ).forEach {
>     it.binaries.framework {
>         baseName = "dateTime"
>     }
> }
>
> sourceSets {
>     val commonMain by getting {
>         dependencies {
>             implementation(libs.kotlin.stdlib)
>         }
>     }
>     val commonTest by getting {
>         dependencies {
>             implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

I **created a normal kotlin Android app (that is not a multiplatform app)** and **successfully pulled the library into the app's dependency.**
In the main activity, it **managed to access the getDateTime method**.
**However, it is not able to resolve the return Object, which is an Instant object.**

The compilations error message is saying

Cannot access class 'kotlinx.datetime.Instant'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

**Below is the extracted build config for the Android app.**

dependencies {implementation("validation:datetime-android:1.0.0")}

Appreciate if someone can guide on how to resolve it, to enable the Android app to recognize the Instant Object, without manually including the kotlinx.datetime library in the normal Kotlin Android app's dependency.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please post your build config. I'd guess maybe you need the dependency to be `api` instead of `implementation`.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your reply. I did try putting api instead of implementation on the Instant dependency within the library project, still cannot recognised by the Android app. I will post the build config soon. Any other possibilities which I should focus on?

Comment: No idea. Config would be helpful.

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the config. Also I am not sure if it is the same issue as what was reported previously (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime/issues/198). But when I change to api, it still don't work for me.